# How can I insert elements into a group of like elements

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have an XML that has a group of like elements and I need to insert elements into the middle of that group

For instance:

```
XML = """
<first>
<second>second element</second>
<third>third element</third>
<third>another third element</third>
<third>yet another third element</third>
</first>
"""
```

I need to be able to insert another element into the middle of the third elements.

I've tried using findall:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser()
root = etree.fromstring(XML, parser)

newElement = etree.Element('third')
newElement.text = 'new element added'

elementList = root.findall('third')
elementList.insert(2, newElement)

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Output:

```
<first>
<second>second element</second>
<third>third element</third>
<third>another third element</third>
<third>yet another third element</third>
</first>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<first>
<second>second element</second>
<third>third element</third>
<third>another third element</third>
<third>new element added</third>
<third>yet another third element</third>
</first>
```

I think I could use `root.insert(<place>, <element>)` but the actual XML I'm trying to change is much larger (too large to post) and not sure if that would be the most Pythonic way of doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're after:

```
xml = etree.fromstring(XML)

for item in xml.xpath('.'):
   newElement = etree.Element('third')  
   newElement.text = "new element added"
   nav = item.findall('third')  
   item.insert(item.index(nav[2]), newElement) 

etree.tostring(xml).decode().replace('\n','')
```

Output:

```
<first>
<second>second element</second>
<third>third element</third>
<third>another third element</third>
<third>new element added</third>
<third>yet another third element</third>
</first>
```

Comment: @fender68dg - Glad it helped!.

Comment: I did have to slightly modify it. For the path in `xml.xpath('.')`, in the real world problem I had, the group of elements was one level deeper so I just had to specify the next level down in the XML for the path in `xpath` in order for it to work else I would get a 'Element is not a child of this node' error. For anyone else that may run into this issue.